# error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_getter at [myapp] lib\screens\home.dart:36)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Widget searchUserList (){
    return StreamBuilder(stream: userStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
      return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(itemCount:snapshot.data?.documents.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.documents[index];
        return Image.network(ds['profileURL']);
      },)
          :Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property to get the documents from a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) was renamed from `documents to` docs` in FlutterFire a few months ago. So you'll want to use:

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index]
```